# Dealing with local state in react and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is it OK to store local state in the `state` object when using react together with redux? Storing everything in the state tree via actions quickly becomes tedious. It feels that some state is relevant only for presentation/display of the app, rather than the logic. By presentation I mean animations/blinking, the expanded/contracted state of panels, the sorting criteria in tables and so on.

Answer (score 14):

This is difficult to answer, because different people will classify different parts of a component as "state".

Since Redux is concerned with *application state*, as a rule of thumb, anything you would expect an application level "undo/redo" button to effect should happen as a Redux Action. The fact that Redux has an undo store plugin is possible only because of the reach of application state.

Certainly some animations would not be undoable, since these should really be connected to changes in the app state, not changes in-and-of themselves. The rest of your examples, though, sound very much like app state. If I sorted a table, and then pressed undo, I would absolutely expect the sorting to be undone.

Comment: I like the suggestion to use application state for things you would expect to be able to undo.

Comment: what about when I want to do something like change the class name when swipe element to do some animation? this stuff should go in the redux action also ?

Answer (score 7):

This is now answered in the [redux FAQs](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate):

> There is no “right” answer for this. Some users prefer to keep every single piece of data in Redux, to maintain a fully serializable and controlled version of their application at all times. Others prefer to keep non-critical or UI state, such as “is this dropdown currently open”, inside a component's internal state.
>
> Using local component state is fine. As a developer, it is your job to determine what kinds of state make up your application, and where each piece of state should live. Find a balance that works for you, and go with it.

Answer (score 5):

As Tyrsius already mentioned - there are different opinions about this.

For us - as a rule of thumb - we make sure to track everything with the application state which we would like to be able to see if we'd connect to some users current session remotely.

If we don't care to see whether the mouse is hovered over some element, we might only use the components state for this (if we need the state then at all).

We have only a few such cases in our scripts though, since we'd like to know exactly what the user sees in most cases for easier debugging.

You're mentioning expanded/collapsed states for panels - we sometimes create components which handle this expanded/collapsed logic for us, so we don't have to write such reducers all the time for every panel we create.

We can use these components like this:

```
<Panel id="somePanelId">some content</Panel>
```

The panel component will make sure to track the panels active state within the application state. This way it's really easy to keep your code simple and not let it explode.

Comment: An example of what this looks like would be nice. I am not sure what you mean by having the component track the state within the application state without using a reducer

Comment: The component does have its own reducer, and dispatches actions depending on how you interact with it.

A toggle for example dispatches an action which sets the visibility of toggle with id "props.id" to "props.active" which is either true or false and the Toggle is connected to the state via mapStateToProps.

The state for the given component is extracted via state.toggles[props.id].

Comment: How is the component reducer connected to the primary store reducer?

Comment: We have a "loader" system in place which automatically combines all reducers which are exposed by modules with the root reducer.

The modules have some informative json file which say something like ```{ reducers: { 'toggles': 'toggleReducer.js' }}```

Comment: That's a very cool idea. You still get a single store object, but with completely encapsulated components. I would be very interested in seeing that loader.

Comment: I was going to write a short article about the structure we use, I'll share it here when it's finished.